# Removing specific lines in SRT file

Tags: file, powershell, subtitle, renaming, mp4box

Im currently working on a PS-script, that will go through my entire libary, locate all mp4 files with subtitles included, and strip them to SRT files with the same name as the video file.

I'm doing the whole thing on a command-line level, but im having issues with a specific set of files. Whenever i strip the SRT file from the MP4 file, it adds extra lines, which messes the subtitles in the video player.

I've tried everything (MP4Box, FFMpeg etc..) but i keep getting the extra lines.

And this is where you guys come in: I need you to help me figuring out how to remove specific lines. Let me show you what i mean:

Original file:
[**REMOVED**] Edit: Look further below, i have pasted the code

Needed output:
[**REMOVED**] Edit: Look further below, i have pasted the code

Notice the fewer line breaks?

Any idea on how i accomplice that using BAT script, powershell or anything like it?

And the solution can't be that if the new line doesn't start with a number, there shouldn't be a line break. Because the text (the actual subtitle-text) in the SRT file might start with a number.

Thanks in advance - i appreciate any help i can get. And sorry for some gramma mistakes every now and then. 2nd language.

### --

**EDIT**
I was asked to paste the text, instead of screenshot:

**Original**

```
1
00:00:10,505 --> 00:00:14,005
Some texting about the video

2
00:00:14,088 --> 00:00:17,713
Some more text

3
00:00:17,796 --> 00:00:21,463
And here it comes

Because the next line is down here

4
00:00:21,546 --> 00:00:24,255
And then it goes on and on

Everytime there is 2 lines in the same textfield

5
00:00:24,338 --> 00:00:30,338
Can you guys help me?

Thanks in advance
```

**Output i want**

```
1
00:00:10,505 --> 00:00:14,005
Some texting about the video

2
00:00:14,088 --> 00:00:17,713
Some more text

3
00:00:17,796 --> 00:00:21,463
And here it comes
Because the next line is down here

4
00:00:21,546 --> 00:00:24,255
And then it goes on and on
Everytime there is 2 lines in the same textfield

5
00:00:24,338 --> 00:00:30,338
Can you guys help me?
Thanks in advance
```

### --

**2ND EDIT**

I do know this is not a free scripting service, and i have provided knowledge here, on a former profile - but OK, feel free to not help me.

I am told to show the "relevent part" of the code. Im not sure how to do this - i can show you how i extract the subtitle. I have tried the following two:

```
Start-Process "C:\bin\FFMpeg.exe" -ArgumentList "-y -i `"$file`" -map 0:`"$ffmpegsubid`" -an -vn -c:s:0 text -f srt `"$subtitle`"" -Wait
Start-Process "C:\Program Files\GPAC\mp4box.exe" -ArgumentList "-srt `"$subid`" `"$file`" -out `"$subtitle`"" -Wait
```

The $subtitle-value is just the inputfile name, with a SRT end

```
$subtitle = $file.Substring(0,$file.Length-3) +"srt"
```

The $subid is found using MediaInfoCLI's tool

```
$subtest = C:\MediaInfoCLI\MediaInfo.exe --Language=raw --Full --Inform="General;%Text_Language_List%" $file
```

The $ffmpegsubid is the same as $subid, just minus 1, because MP4Box and FFMpeg counts streams differently

```
$ffmpegsubid = ($subid-1)
```

And the subtest becomes the subid, depending on what language you aim for. Its over 200 lines of "elseif", to make sure that i hit all different combinations. (like en / sp / po  and en / po /sp )

But none of this has anything to do with the question. How do i remove the unwanted lines from my output file? I made a script remove lines, if the next one doesnt start with a number, but that doesn't help me right now, so no reason to post it.

Anyway - thanks in advance - appreciate it :)

### --

**3RD EDIT**

Someone posted the following solution, before deleting it:

```
Get-Content $file | ForEach-Object {
    if (!($previousline)) {
        $previousline
    }
    if ([Helpers]::IsNumeric($_) -and $previousline -eq "") {
        $previousline
    } elseif (!([Helpers]::IsNumeric($_)) -and $previousline -ne "") {
         $previousline
    }
    $previousline = $_
} | Set-Content $output
Get-Content $file | Select-Object -Last 1 | Add-Content $output
```

However, all that does it generating the following error:

[Powershell Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cq5sk.png)

Comment: Please post the actual sample contents as text rather than as screenshots of notepad

Comment: As you wish, sir :)

Comment: As [SO] is a programmers site you should show your code efforts to get help where you got stuck - this isn't a free scripting service.

Comment: Show us the relevant part of your PS code.

Comment: The "solution" in the question does not appear to set any value in the $file variable. That is what the error message is reporting. I know this because reading error messages is occasionally my superpower. Sometimes it is not my superpower.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
$path = "" #Path File

$File = Get-Content $Path

$newFile = "$ENV:USERPROFILE\Desktop\newfile.srt" # new file

$i = 0

New-Item -Path $newFile -ItemType File | out-null

Foreach ($Line in $File) {
    $PreviousLine = $File[$i - 1]
    $NextLine = $File[$i + 1]
    $timeLine = $File[$i + 2]

    $regex = "^[0-9]+$"
    $regexTime = "^[0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{1,2},[0-9]{1,3} --> [0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{1,2},[0-9]{1,3}$"

    if ($Line -ne "" -or  ($PreviousLine -ne "" -and $NextLine -match  $regex -and $timeLine -match $regexTime )) {
        Add-Content -Path $newFile -Value $Line
       }
    $i ++
}
```

This script will create a new file with the lines that meets this conditions:
 1. It isn't empty string.
 2. If it is empty string, then the previous line isn't empty string and the next line is a number.

You must add the path of the file in the variable $Path and modify the variable $newFile.

Comment: This is good, but what if the 2 "text" lines are: 1) How much does that cost? 2) 8 dollars ma'am. Then the line would not be removed from the file, and only the first line would be visible in a video player :-/

Comment: Yes, that was true, if a text line was only a number, then the empty line wouldn't be removed. So I add a variable "$timeLine" and "$regexTime", with this modification the script will only add the empty string line that separate each block of text.

Comment: Sorry, for the late reply. Made a small beta test - seems to work. I'll implement it into my code, and if it works, i'll mark as answer and drop a link, so if anyone else could use it - go nuts

Thanks again :-)